# What's a good reference for learning about recombinant proteins?

Tags: proteins, literature, book-recommendation

I'm looking for books and articles that can bring me up to speed on the design, expression, and purification of mammalian proteins in recombinant systems, both in *E. coli* and in more complex systems like CHO or *Sf9* cells. I have a weak but functional background in general molecular biology.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn yourself your first badge. Have a nice stay!

Answer (score 1):

i would start by searching [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) literature database for relevant articles using this [query](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22protein%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20and%20%22expression%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20and%20%22purification%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20and%20%22recombinant%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20and%20%22mammalian%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20and%20(%22E.%20coli%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20or%20%22CHO%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D%20or%20%22Sf9%22%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D)):

```
"protein"[Title/Abstract] and "expression"[Title/Abstract] and "purification"[Title/Abstract] and "recombinant"[Title/Abstract] and "mammalian"[Title/Abstract] and ("E. coli"[Title/Abstract] or "CHO"[Title/Abstract] or "Sf9"[Title/Abstract])
```

which returns 116 articles (including 7 reviews).

Comment: Hello! This question was deemed worth of an answer, so why not upvote it? [Vote early, vote often](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/vote-early-vote-often?rq=1) to encourage new users and keep the community alive!

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Except that it is not an answer but a suggestion as to how to find an answer.

Comment: @David "why not upvote it" - "it" was referred to the question, not the answer. I wanted to incite the answerer to upvote the question. I didn't express myself clearly, my bad!